# Wallet doesn‘t show correct Balance

Tags: iri-node, wallet, balances

My wallet didn‘t show the correct Balance, some MIOTA were missing. I hadn‘t missed a Snapshot but was able to restore the right balance by generating addresses. My question is what led to that kind of incorrect display?

- Was it an error on the full-node I was connected to?
- Do some full-nodes perform local snapshots already?

Answer (score 1):

Unconfirmed transactions are not guaranteed to be synchronized across all nodes (in fact, some nodes intentionally drop them sometimes).

In case your current balance was last altered (by **value** transactions) **before** the last snapshot, and all you did **after** that snapshot was to attach (*unconfirmed*) addresses, it could have happened that these addresses disappeared from the tangle as they were unconfirmed.

You noticed that you can regenerate and attach these regenerated transactions and the money comes back. You could also try to get these transactions confirmed (by reattaching/promoting) so that they cannot disappear again until the next snapshot.